# Why a JSON error in python selenium request?

Tags: python, json, selenium

I don't understand the following error I have using python selenium. Can you explain please this error?

```
def getdriver(url):
    s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    driver.minimize_window()
    driver.get(url)
    return(driver)


driver = getdriver("https://address.com")
    driver.switch_to.frame('idIframeEngagement')
    equipes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'menu')
    for elt in equipes:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, elt.text.encode('utf-8'))))).click()
```

I connect to a webpage. I get all the links I need and the I want to visit all of them using a loop but I get all this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\code\python\Avenir\resu\main.py", line 77, in <module>
    getinfoFFBB()
  File "C:\code\python\Avenir\resu\main.py", line 57, in getinfoFFBB
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, elt)))).click()
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 81, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 312, in _predicate
    target = driver.find_element(*target)  # grab element at locator
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 855, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 426, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 342, in execute
    data = utils.dump_json(params)
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\utils.py", line 23, in dump_json
    return json.dumps(json_struct)
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\elman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: why the `encode()` in `elt.text.encode('utf-8')`? And it looks there are redundant pair of braces there

Comment: You are right. That is my mistake. Without the "encode" it works. Thanks a lot